# Concatenate back with `np.split_array` divided dataframes which were used in a loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to concatenate back with `np.split_array` divided dataframes which were used in a loop?

I have a dataframe as shapefile (or csv would be the same, except the geometry part) and some other dataframes. To fasten the whole process I split `df` into 10 parts, then run a loop and get 10 separate dataframes.

After that, I could export each dataframe as shp or csv file, then write a code that loops through the directory, finds corresponding files and merge them, but I would like to do that without exporting files and directly after the loop ends. Is this could be done?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = gpd.read_csv(r'E:\...\Polygons.shp')
some_other_df = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\Small_polygon.shp')
points = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\points.shp')

df_split = np.array_split(df, 10)

for i, v in enumerate(df_split, 0):

    # do something here
    points_clip = gpd.clip(points, v)
    some_other_df_Clip = gpd.clip(some_other_df, v)

    new_dataframe = ...
    # here I get 10 separate dataframes

    new_dataframe.to_file(fr'W:\...\final_{i}.shp')

    # how to merge all 10 new_dataframe to one?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
list_of_dataframes = []

for i, v in enumerate(df_split, 0):
    #Your logic goes here
    list_of_dataframes.append(new_dataframe)

df_final = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes, ignore_index=True)
```